# How do I convert this T-SQL query to use an explicit join syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following Select statement, but want to change it to use iner joins as I believe they are more efficient, but not too sure where to start.

```
DECLARE @myNameID  int
DECLARE @myAddressID  int
DECLARE @myFirstName nvarchar(256)

SET @myNameID = 1
SET @myAddressID =1
SET @myFirstName='Nathan'

SELECT @myNameID = myNameID 
    FROM

        NameTable Name,
        AddressTable Address,
        CountryTable Country

    WHERE
        Name.[FirstName] = @ myFirstName and 
        Address. AddressID = @ myAddressID and
        Address.CountryID = Country.CountryID  and
        Name.SecondID = Country.SecondID
```

Comment: You are already using Inner joins, you are just not using the "inner join" syntax. The execution plan should be the same. I do however, believe that the INNER JOIN syntax makes the intent clearer.

Comment: The inner join syntax is not "more efficient" than what you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT @myNameID = myNameID     
FROM  NameTable Name
INNER JOIN  CountryTable Country ON Name.SecondID = Country.SecondID
INNER JOIN  AddressTable Address ON Address.CountryID = Country.CountryID     
WHERE Name.[FirstName] = @myFirstName 
and Address. AddressID = @myAddressID
```

Comment: Thanks...I'm just starting to get the hang of SQL!!

Comment: The only thing I would change about Andrew's solution, and the original query, is the use of the word Name as an alias for NameTable. While it will work fine, I tend to try to reduce possible confusion by not using reserved words as aliases or table names.

Comment: Cool, the table name isnt really name, ive just tried to make the names easier to relate to.

Comment: i think you want to do SELECT  myNameID= @myNameID  ??